Data and Area folder is not created by template by default in ASP.NET Core MVC project
I created an ASP.NET Core MVC web app project. I expected to get area and data folder in this but it's not showing up by default. What should I do in this case? Please help me to figure this out.
The project I selected
Here are the folders I am getting by default:
enter image description here
I want to get a idea of selection project which will comes with default area and data folder.

If you want to automatically create the Area and Data folder when choose the ASP.NET Core MVC web app template, you can select the Authentication Type > Individual Account like below to achieve your requirement.

